# Button with input element inside

Tags: html, button, input

I have an input element (type numeric) inside button element. One thing bothers me. When I am finishing editing input value either by keyboard either by mouse (clicking up/down) it automatically sends value to server like outer button has been clicked. How to cancel this default behaviour and have only outer button clicking linked with action to send to server.

[image: button clicks when input changed]

```html
<button onclick="window.location.href='?N='+document.getElementById('minutes_forward').value;">
<input type="number" id="minutes_forward" name="minutes_forward" value="20"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
```

Comment: A button is not a visual styling element but a trigger to run a script. It cannot validly contain another interactive element such as an input element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the propagation of the event you can use `event.stopPropagation();`.

So in your code you could do:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='?N='+document.getElementById('minutes_forward').value;">
    <input type="number" id="minutes_forward" name="minutes_forward" value="20" onclick="event.stopPropagation();"/>
</button>
```

To know more about that check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: This is working like i wanted. I read about this here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2906586/4292145 and decided to make this way like button with children.